# Number of Triangles in a Vertex in C

Tags: c, graph, adjacency-list

I'm having some difficulties to develop a fuction to count the number of triangles in each vertex of a Graph. This graph is an adjacency list. I did 
the Is_Edge function that returns 1 if there is an edge between V1 and V2, this might help.Any hint? The structs are below:

```
struct AdjListNode
{
    int dest;
    int TrianglesNumber;
    int weight;
    struct AdjListNode* next;
};

struct AdjList
{
    struct AdjListNode *head; 
};

struct Graph
{
    int V;
    struct AdjList* array;
};

int Is_Edge(struct Graph *Graph,int V1,int V2){
    int find=0;
    if(V1 > Graph->V || V2 > Graph->V)
        return 0;
    else{
        struct AdjListNode *aux = Graph->array[V1].head;
        while((aux!=NULL)&&(!find)){
                if(aux->dest == V2)
                    find = 1;
                else
                    aux = aux->prox;
        }
        return(find);
    }
}
```

Comment: I take it you are defining a "triangle" to be a three-edge cycle without any self edges.  You could solve the problem in various ways; one would be a bounded depth-first search based on your adjacency lists.  That is, explore the three-edge paths starting at the vertex in question, and count how many end back at that vertex.  Your data structure suggests a directed graph; if it is instead undirected then you probably would need to divide by two to account for the two different directions in which you can traverse each triangle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not write code until you know what logic or algorithm you want the code to implement.

If you know which vertices are connected by an edge, say you have a function `Connected(i, j)`, and the total number of vertices `N`, then you can count the number of triangles sharing vertex `k` using (pseudocode)

```
Function triangles_at_vertex(k):
    Count = 0
    For i = 1 to N:
        If i != k AND Connected(i, k):
            For j = 1 to N:
                If j != i AND j != k AND Connected(i, j):
                    Count = Count + 1
                End if
            End For
        End If
    End For
    Return Count
End Function
```

However, the above function does not use adjacency lists at all.

---

Let's say you do have the adjacency list for vertex `k`, as well as for all vertices adjacent to `k`. One way to count the triangles is to count the number of unique pairs of connected vertices also connected to vertex `k`:

```
Function triangles_at_vertex(k):
    pairs = Empty
    kList = Adjacency_list(k)
    For i in kList:
       iList = Adjacency_list(i)
       For j in iList:
           If (j in kList):
               If ((Pair(i,j) NOT in pairs) AND
                  ((Pair(j,i) NOT in pairs):
                   Add Pair(i, j) to pairs
               End If
           End If
       End For
    End For
    Return Count(pairs)
End Function
```

The `pairs` above can be a list, ordered set (array of pairs), or an unordered set. Note that it cannot have as many members as the adjacency list for vertex `k`, because all vertices in all triangles we are looking for must be in the adjacency list for `k`.

---

We can avoid the `pairs` set/list, if we assume that all adjacency lists are complete -- in the sense that if `k` is listed in `i`'s adjacency list, then `i` is listed in `k`'s adjacency list too. Often, only one half of the adjacency is stored, for smaller memory use.

Then, we know that we count each pair exactly twice, because we count both `i,j` and `j,i`:

```
Function triangles_at_vertex(k):
    Count = 0
    kList = Adjacency_list(k)
    For i in kList:
       iList = Adjacency_list(i)
       For j in iList:
           If (j in kList):
               Count = Count + 1
           End If
       End For
    End For
    Return Count / 2
End Function
```

---

Pick your algorithm first, and then start coding.

Comment: Thank u for the suggestions, I'll think about them.

Comment: @Jessy: I personally write a lot of very small test programs, just to see what a tentative idea would look like in practice. Typically, I only implement the hardest parts (those I haven't implemented enough times to already know what works for the kind of situation I'm thinking of). I keep these in a directory structure, one directory per snippet (named with a number and a minimum-length-description), and a huge comment (or a text file) in the directory to describe the problem and my ideas. These come in *very* handy, so would recommend trying out a similar approach.